# Is it considered bad practice to manipulate a queried database document before sending to the client in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So I spent too long trying to figure out how to manipulate a returned database document (using mongoose) using transform and virtuals, but for my purposes, those aren't options. The behaviour I desire is very similar to that of a transform (in which I delete a property), but I only want to delete the property from the returned document IFF it satisfies a requirement calculated using the req.session.user/req.user object (I'm using PassportJS, but any equivalent session user suffices). Obviously, there is no access to the request object in a virtual or transform, and so I can't do the calculation.

Then it dawned on me that I could just query normally and manipulate the returned object in the callback before I send it to the client. And I could put it in a middleware function that looks nice, but something tells me this is a hacky thing to do. I'm presenting an api to the client that does not reflect the data stored/retrieved directly from the database. It may also clutter up my route configuration if I have middleware like this all over making it harder to maintain code. Below is an example of what the manipulation looks like:

```
app.route('/api/items/:id').get(manipulateItem, sendItem);
app.param('id', findUniqueItem);

function findUniqueItem(req, res, next, id) {
    Item.findUniqueById(id, function(err, item) {
        if (!err) { req.itemFound = item; }
        next();
    }
}

function manipulateItem(req, res, next) {
    if (req.itemFound.people.indexOf(req.user) === -1) {
        req.itemFound.userIsInPeopleArray = false;
    } else {
        req.itemFound.userIsInPeopleArray = true;
    }
    delete req.itemFound.people;
}

function sendItem(req, res, next) {
    res.json(req.itemFound);
}
```

I feel like this is a workaround to a problem with a simpler solution, but I'm not sure what that solution is.

Comment: This is what middleware is for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing hacky about the act of modifying it.
It's all a matter of *when* you modify it.

For toy servers, and learning projects, the answer is whenever you want.
In production environments, you want to do your transform on your way out of your system, and into the next system (the next system might be the end user; it might be another server; it might be another big block of functionality in your own server, that *shouldn't* have access to more information that it needs to do its job).

```
getItemsFromSomewhere()
  .then(transformToTypeICanUse)
  .then(filterBasedOnMyExpectations)
  .then(doOperations)
  .then(transformToTypeIPromisedYou)
  .then(outputToNextSystem);
```

That example might not be super-helpful in terms of an actual *how*, but that's sort of the point.
As you can see, you could link that system of events up to another system of events (that does its own transform to its own data-structure, does its own filtering/mapping, transforms that data into whatever its API promises, and passes it along to the next system, and eventually out to the end user).

I think part of the sense of "hacking" comes from bolting the result of the async process onto `req`, where `req` gets injected from step to step, through the middleware.

That said:

```
function eq (a) {
  return function (b) { return a === b; };
}

function makeOutputObject (inputObject, personWasFound) {
  // return whatever you want
}

var personFound = req.itemFound.people.some(eq(req.user));
var outputObject = makeOutputObject(req.itemFound, personFound);
```

Now you aren't using the actual `delete` keyword, or modifying the call-to-call state of that `itemFound` object.

You're separating your view-based logic from your app-based logic, but without the formal barriers (can always be added later, if they're needed).